# Keyboard shifts bottom tabs button up and also hides EditText and CheckBox in android

Tags: android, android-keypad

In layout I have 2 `EditText`, one `Button` and a `CheckBox`. My whole layout is inside `ScrollView` so that it shifts up when keyboard is displayed.

Now problem is that when keyboard is shown it also moves bottom tab buttons up. User can scroll to see `EditText` and `CheckBox`. But I dont want bottom tabs to move up. So I used this instead

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Using this stops shifting of bottom tabs but it also stops scrolling of my layout having edittext, button and checkbox.

How can I have keyboard not shifts bottom tabs with it and also when keyboard is shown my layout having edittext and checkbox is moved up so that user can see layout.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The best way to cop up with the shifting problem is : just don't define this "android:windowSoftInputMode" parameter in android manifest. It works fine without it.

Here is how I mostly declare my activity in manifest:

```
 <activity android:name="com.lisnx.ui.TabView"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
```

Comment: When I removed windowsSoftInput it shifts bottom tabs button up and also hides edittexts.

Comment: This is how I usually declare my activity(please see edits):-